# How to get related model fields in template

Tags: django

I have the following two models

```
LocalPart (models.Model):
...
```

and

```
GlobalPart (models.Model):
....
localpart = models.ManyToManyField (LocalPart, related_name = 'localpart')
...
```

I want to reference the related GlobalParts when I call a LocalPart.

How do I do this?

I have tried the following: {{ part.localpart_set.all }} and {{ part.GlobalPart_set.all }} where part is an entry in localpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
localpart = LocalPart.objects.get(...)
localpart.localpart.all()
```

...where a related_name of "localpart" is a bit confusing here.

Comment: Please read this first, then follow implementing my example. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for

Comment: Thanks that worked. Out of curiosity, when do you the _set value?

Comment: When determining a `related_name` think about the relationship in reverse. If I have a `LocalPart` and I want to get all of its `GlobalPart`s, I would use ________. If you fill in "localpart" as you have, currently, it obviously makes no sense. Something like "globalparts" would be more appropriate.

Comment: "_set" ist used in ForeignKeys: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: No, `_set` is used when you *don't* set a related name explicitly, as you have.